# Php Rest API path hierarchy w/o id

Tags: php, javascript, rest

I am reading a book and searching on the internet about this API path hirearchy and have not found anything solid yet, what I really want to know is where to put the id to retrieve/update/delete hirearchical API methods.

For instance I know I can do:

```
authority/resource/[id]/catalog/category1/category2
```

also:

```
authority/resource/catalog/category1/category2/[id]
```

in this previous example the problem comes when the next path from category2 (id) can be a numeric field to lets say update a value.

I do not really know if there is a standard about this way of building an state transfer API.
I can actually build my own and I was wondering if there are any standards or some aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" allows lot's of interpretations on how you can design your hierarchy. There is not really THE way to do it.

However I think that this presentation:
https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design
Is a good read on the topic. It outlines some design choices and also shows how some popular APIs (such as the ones offered by Google or Twitter) choose to design their URLs.

Comment: It's book Web API design gives nice information about api structure, something also I forgot was about the topic they provide "sweep complexity under the ‘?’"".